# Error: '' is not a valid port number while trying to bring up Python flask application on GKE

Tags: python, flask, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to bring up a python flask application using gunicorn. I am referring to [this code](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#run_pubsub_dockerfile-python) to create an image and then bring up a pod/deployment/service on GKE.

Pod bring up fails on GKE with "ContainersReady: False". On probing ContainerLogs i could see following error

```
Error: '' is not a valid port number
```

i have changed the dockerfile and rebuild the image by changing the following, but it error remains same.

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

i guess i am missing something basic here. Not sure what is it..

Comment: what happens if you run this as a container locally using docker instead of in a k8s cluster?

Comment: Could you please share your complete Dockerfile.

Comment: It's in the link in the original post.

Comment: Haven't verified on local Docker machine. Will test and let you know Patrick.

Comment: I used the same guide to spawn this image and got the same message: `Error: '' is not a valid port number`. After updating the `Dockerfile` with `--bind 0.0.0.0:8000` I was able to run this image successfully. Please check if your pod has the updated/newest image with `--bind` updated as it looks you are using older version.

Comment: How does your dockerfile look Dawid. Is it the same as what's in the link?

Comment: @Prashant I downloaded the files with `$ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git`. The only thing I changed was the `Dockerfile` line with `gunicorn` to: `CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app`. Then I built a **new** image (different tag), deleted the deployment and applied new one with new image.

Comment: Weird. As you can see I have tried the same. Will try and let you know

Comment: @Prashant have you managed to solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Please check this example: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/deploying-a-language-specific-app#python_1

After adding

```
env:
  - name: PORT
    value: "8080"
```

under 'containers' in your deployment.yaml it shoud work.